# ORA-06512 and ORA-01403 no data found

Tags: plsql

I keep getting the below error upon executing the tax_calc_sf function on SQL developer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFKrv.png)
Also I am not sure why it always disconnects from database immediately after the process is exits.Any help with this would be appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tax_calc2_sf
(p_id NUMBER,
 p_sub NUMBER)
 RETURN NUMBER
 IS
 lv_tax_num NUMBER(5,2) :=0;
 BEGIN
 SELECT p_sub*t.taxrate tax
 INTO lv_tax_num
 FROM bb_basket b, bb_tax t
 WHERE b.shipstate = t.state
 AND b.idBasket = p_id;
 RETURN lv_tax_num;
 END;
```

I have tried adding a exception block as below but that does not change anything but the same error as shown in the image above still repeats.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKcaX.png)

Comment: ORA-01403 means "no data found"; it is raised by the SELECT statement. Although difficult to read, the second screenshot suggests that you should have fixed it with the exception handling section. Please, post sample data and the final function code - to do so, **edit** the question, don't post anything as images any more as they are impossible to be read.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of your [PL/SQL] function – `tax_calc2_sf` – the [SELECT INTO](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/selectinto_statement.htm#LNPLS01345) statement should return precisely one row. If it does not return precisely one row, you will get one of the following [predefined exceptions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00703)

- NO_DATA_FOUND if the SELECT returns zero rows
- TOO_MANY_ROWS if the SELECT returns more than one row

Adding an [exception handler](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/errors.htm#LNPLS00701) does not prevent the exception from occurring, it just allows you to perform custom handling.

So ask yourself, what should function `tax_calc2_sf` do if the SELECT returns no rows. Should the function return null? Should it return zero? Should it throw an exception?

Similarly, you need to decide what to do when the SELECT returns more than one row.

Alternatively, you could first perform a `SELECT count(*)` which will always return precisely one row and so will not throw any exceptions. Then you can decide how to proceed depending on whether the count is zero, one or more than one.

By the way, it is recommended to use [ANSI join syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046) when you query more than one database table.

```sql
SELECT p_sub*t.taxrate tax
  INTO lv_tax_num
  FROM bb_basket b
  JOIN bb_tax t
    ON b.shipstate = t.state
 WHERE b.idBasket = p_id;
```